# php date formatting with MySQL SHOW TABLE STATUS

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

probably missing something simple:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','xxx','xxx');

$db=mysql_select_db('xxx');

$sql = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `name`=\"my_table\"");

$foo=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

return $foo['Update_time'];

// returns 2010-03-31 16:51:06
?>
```

how do i format this. I tried using

```
date('l jS F Y @ H:i:s', $foo['Update_time']);
```

but this returns:

**Thursday 1st January 1970 @ 01:33:30**

presumably as date() expects a timestamp.

thanks..im sure this is very obvious but my minds gone blank

Answer (score 3):

The [**`date`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function expects an [UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as its second parameter -- and not a string containing a date.

This means you have to convert that string to a timestamp -- which can be done using the [**`strtotime`**](http://fr.php.net/strtotime) function :

```
$ts = strtotime($foo['Update_time']);
echo date('l jS F Y @ H:i:s', $ts);
```

Note 1 : the `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` format is well understood by `strtotime` ; which is often helpful, when dealing with dates that come from MySQL.

Note 2 : Using `date` and `strtotime`, which work on timestamps *(reprenseted as 32 bits integers, counting the number of seconds since `1970-01-01`)*, you will be limited to dates between 1970 and 2038 ; if you need to work with dates outside of that range, you'll have to use the [`DateTime` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
date('l jS F Y @ H:i:s', strtotime($foo['Update_time']));
```

[strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) will take a date string and turn it into a timestamp, which you can then use with `date()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strtotime` function:

```
date('l jS F Y @ H:i:s', strtotime($foo['Update_time']));
```